# File locking and unlocking in C, and writing shell script to test the same

Tags: c, shell, filesystems, locks

I am making a rudimentary text editor using C which can open, edit and save files. But I need help in implementing advisory locking of the file that I have been working on. For eg. Suppose I make a file using my program named "Hello.txt". Now, when I am operating on the file, like editing or deleting contents I need the program to warn the user that the file is currently opened and is being used by a process already. Although it won't be a hard lock, the user can then choose to edit it even after the warning.

Also, if anyone can help with the shell script to test this program or guide me in the right direction, would be really appreciated.

Comment: There is an editor call emacs that is public source that has good file locking.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html#File-Locks. has the documentation if you want to read and emulate this method

Comment: Unix or Windows ?

Comment: Since the locking is advisory, it won't stop the user from executing `rm file` or `cp /etc/passwd file` or `cat /etc/group >> file` or `mv file /some/where/else` or any other mischievous way of modifying the file while the editor has it open.  At most, you can stop concurrent executions of the same editor on the same file — programs like `vim` manage that.  They also detect when the file is modified behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This answer applies only to Linux system.

You can take one of a few routes to implement a warning/soft locking of files.

1. Use the POSIX 'flock' system call, Ir
2. Use a lock file.

Most editors (vim, emacs) use the 2nd approach, and leverage the lock file to save uncommitted modifications. However, given that the OP is building a simple editor, this seems to be an overkill.

To implement the soft locking, the editor should perform the following on startup:

1. Issue non-blocking Exclusive Lock
2. If not granted - warn the user about concurrent editing
3. Replace the exclusive lock with a shared lock

When the editing session terminates:

1. Unlock the file

To emphasize: neither of these solutions is likely to detect when the text file is opened by other programs/editors.

Comment: It can apply to most POSIX-like systems, not just Linux.